# Private Endpoint between Aure App Service and MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to follow this design by Microsoft to securely connect an Azure App Service to MySQL Database.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/private-web-app/private-web-app#architecture

I have:

- VNet (Address Space 10.1.0.0/16)

  - Subnet - 'app_subnet' 10.1.2.0/24 (Service Endpoint(Microsoft.Web))
  - Subnet - 'mysql_subnet' 10.1.1.0/24
- App Service (Linux, Dotnet Core App)

  - Connected to Vnet Subnet 'app_subnet'
  - AppSettings:

    - WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER = 168.63.129.16
    - WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL = 1
- Private Endpoint (MySQLEndPoint)

  - private DNS privatelink-mysql-database-azure-com ZONE privatelink.mysql.database.azure.com
  - Subnet 'mysql_subnet'
- MySQL Database

  - Private Endpoint 'MySQLEndPoint'

*Anything missing tell me and I can add it

Running the App to connect gets a Connection Timeout.

I have gone into the Kudu BASH and ran:
ping -c 3 .mysql.database.azure.com
Got response:
PING .privatelink.mysql.database.azure.com (10.1.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

I have also got the credentials down and tested them locally, which I can connect to the DB with my IP whitelisted.

I can't see/think of anything else to test/try.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue was the Private Link name needs to be valid from this list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns

As I was using Terraform, I assumed the name property was just a friendly name.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_dns_zone